# Biztalk forced suspense?

Tags: biztalk, suspend

I am getting the error:

> This service instance was suspended by
>   a BizTalk administrator.

However I didn't force a suspense and it's on my local machine. I get this message all the time with every item i input. The thing is I changed a line in assembly which was a small translation, however this couldn't possibly be the cause. So I was wondering if anyone has encountered this problem before and what they did to fix this.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you rebuild your Visual Studio project, depending upon the BTS project settings.  A newly built DLL cannot be deployed while there are running instances. Check your project properties page (from the Project in Sln Explorer, right-click -> Properties).

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever changed the logon as? this might be the cause of the error.

Check the account which the biztalk is running under:
1- open services console
2- right click the biztalk service instance
3- click properties and click the "logon as tab".
4- Make sure the user is an administrator or part of these groups:
     - Administrators
     - Biztalk Application Users
     - Biztalk Isolated Host Users.